# Xpages Combobox setting values in managed bean

Tags: xpages, argument-passing, managed-bean

I am trying to pass arguments to a managed bean. 
The bean is configured and works, has two methods "getResponsible" and "setResponsible". 
Calling "myLookup.responsible" works.

I cannot pass arguments to my bean, and can't figure out why. 
The below code does not work.

```
  <xp:comboBox id="comboBox1">
  <xp:selectItems>
  <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{myLookup.setResponsible("Something")}]]>
  </xp:this.value>
  </xp:selectItems>
  </xp:comboBox>
```

As soon as I type paranthesis ")", "(" or semicolon ";" i get error "Error in EL syntax". I guess I am making some fundamental mistake here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of expression language does not allow parameters to easily be passed. This option may work http://blog.defrog.nl/2012/04/settings-bean-parameterized-method-call.html.

If parameters are required, I usually use SSJS, so:

```
#{javascript:myLookup.setResponsible("Something");
```

If the options won't vary during the page's life, you can always compute on page load, so:

```
${javascript:myLookup.setResponsible("Something");
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you just made a simple "typo" as Paul stated indirectly in his reply. You wrote Javascript code but did not include the "javascript:" in the beginning of your expression.

If, however, you do want to use arguments with EL then have a look at this [very interesting article](http://blog.defrog.nl/2012/04/settings-bean-parameterized-method-call.html). I haven't tried it out myself yet (but am going to do shortly) - but the two different examples (have a look at the comments) seem very interesting when you want to use EL. And I prefer EL over SSJS.

/John

Comment: Just beat me to it, Paul ;-)

Comment: Yes, I would very much like to avoid SSJS, that is why I made the managed bean in the first place. :) I will read the article and try to avoid SSJS all together. Thanks!